# Passing object to reusable view get error: null is not object (evaluating ...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create a Component which is getting data from server then shows data on the screen. The screen look good when I use react-native views directly.

After that, I refactor the code to make it reusable by moving a snippet of code to a new component (`TwoGroupItemsView`):

```
export class MainComponent extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     return fetch('https://mycompany.com/items')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            items: json.data,
        }, function(){

        });
      }
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <View>
         <View>
            {
              this.state.items != null &&
              <TwoGroupItemsView title={'Group 1'} items={this.state.items}/>
            }
          </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
}

class TwoGroupItemsView extends View {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 16}}>
        //... FlatList for items array
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I always get:

> ## TypeError: null is not an object

When evaluating '`this.state.items`'.

Can you show me the way to create my own reusable views?

Comment: Show the part `componentDidMount() {
     //... get data then store to this.state.items
   }`. The error is likely there.

Comment: I have added the part of componentDidMount. Could you please explain more about it? It works normally if I use plain views of react-native instead create my own View.

Comment: @R.Kaka Could you please console log the response you are getting from API!, another point, why are you extending View not Component in TwoGroupItemsView ?

Comment: @R.Kaka try again using : `async componentDidMount() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is being set asynchronously. Try explicitly initializing it before the Promise resolves. Some possibilities below.

Declaring the initial state:

```js
export class MainComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: true, // sample values
    items: null 
  }
```

Or setting in the constructor:

```js
export class MainComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true, // sample values
      items: null 
    };
 }
```

Or strengthening the guards:

```jsx
   render() {
     return (
       <View>
         <View>
            {
              this.state && this.state.items != null &&
              <TwoGroupItemsView title={'Group 1'} items={this.state && this.state.items}/>
            }
          </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
```

Comment: I've tried initialize at either constructor or componentDidMount. But the Error still happens. Stack trace shows error at passing the items to TwoGroupItemsView.

Comment: Even when you set `items: null`? Because this shouldn't render `TwoGroupItemsView`.

Comment: Yes, even set items: null. It always happen at items={this.state.items}. But you can see, I have check null before it this.state.items != null &&
              <TwoGroupItemsView title={'Group 1'} items={this.state.items}/>

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have tried all three possibilities, they worked for me in a simulation using your code. Hopefully one works for you.

Comment: I would like to say thanks for your help. I've figured out what's wrong. Everything should going fine which what we show here. Yes! When I refactor the code, I missy replace some state.items to props.items. It properly issue in side my own View instead of passing data error as react-native stack trace showing.

Answer (score 0):

Re write your render function.

```
 render() {
     return (
       <View>
         <View>
            {
              this.state.items ? 
              <TwoGroupItemsView title={'Group 1'} items={this.state.items}/> : null
            }
          </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
```